# Dynamic title AND content in Jekyll

Tags: web, jekyll, liquid, github-pages, static-site

I have a page whose structure is somewhat like this

```
---
layout: contents
title: contents
description: Contents of the posts.
permalink: contents/
---


      <ul class="posts">
        {% for post in site.posts %}
            {% if post.categories != "tips" %}
          <h2><a class="post-heading" href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
          <p> {{ post.description }} </p>
          <p class="date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</p>
          <hr class="hr-color"></hr>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul >
```

Currently the URL of this page is set according to `permalinks`(BASE_URL/contents). I want that when a user clicks on an option( Android,Java,Web are the options) in the previous page, i get the URL of this page as `BASE_URL/android` or `BASE_URL/Java` and also display the contents of that category.

Is this possible using jekyll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions :

#### 1 - Using a plugin

You can use [this category archive generator](https://github.com/shigeya/jekyll-category-archive-plugin)

#### 2 - Using hand crafted pages

If you cannot use plugin (gh-pages) you can make a page per category, like this :

**android.html**

```
---
layout: category
title: Android
permalink: android/
---
```

**_layouts/category.hmtl**

```
---
layout: default
---

<ul class="posts">
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if post.categories contains page.title %}
      <h2><a class="post-heading" href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      <p> {{ post.description }} </p>
      <p class="date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</p>
      <hr class="hr-color"></hr>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul >
```

Comment: Point 2 is not a good solution actually. Will look into Point 1. I am upvoting for now. Will accept if this works.